Accessing A K8S Pod From The Outside World Using Port Forwarding
I have a 3 node K8S cluster, comprised of machines NODE-1, NODE-2 and NODE-3 where I have a pod running an application on port 7200 on one of them.
I have a 4th machine, say NODE-4 where I have kubectl installed, through which I manage this 3 node cluster.
Now I setup port forwarding using kubectl port-forward to access this application. The
exact command is
kubectl port-forward -n dhiwakar my-app 9200:7200

It works fine when I try to access the app from this 4th machine itself
curl -X GET http://localhost:9200

The problem occurs when I try to access this application from a 5th machine, say NODE-5 like so
curl -X GET http://NODE-4:9200

I get a connection refused error, which is weird as NODE-5 can access applications hosted on docker containers on this NODE-4 and yet somehow the pod that was port-forwarded on NODE-4 can't be accessed by the outside world by referencing NODE-4:9200
Is Kubernetes' port forwarding similar in functioning to https://docs.docker.com/engine/network/#published-ports ?

You almost certainly do not want kubectl port-forward as the primary way to access your application: it depends on the port-forward process staying up, the persistent connection to the cluster does occasionally close unexpectedly, and the port-forward will only target a single replica of your frontend container.  Do you want a NodePort or LoadBalancer-type Service instead, or perhaps an Ingress or Gateway?

@DavidMaze the question is pretty simple, given what I've explained, should I be able to access my application from the outside world, say NODE-5 by simply executing curl -X GET http://NODE-4:9200 ? Assume that there is no firewall or any network restriction between NODE-4 & NODE-5

windows host + vagrant + kubectl port-forward: stuck inside vagrant doesn't sound similar from the question title, but its answers discuss kubectl port-forward's IP bindings.  Does that question help you?

Difference between kubectl port-forwarding and NodePort service may also be informative, and probably answers your higher-level question of accessing the application from outside the cluster.

You're a god @DavidMaze, thank you so much, I wasn't aware of the fact that kubectl port-forward binds to 127.0.0.1 by default :)
